# Generating .doc files through phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I noticed phpMyAdmin has a feature that automatically generates CSV, Microsoft Word, SQL etc.

Is it possible to create a link on a webpage which makes use of this feature. Thus preventing the need for the user to go into the administrative phpMyAdmin panel.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't want to let any user have access to your phpMyAdmin UI. There are too many malicious things that could be done. Better: There are many libraries in php that can help you do this.

Php-Excel library: http://code.google.com/p/php-excel/

Php-word library: http://www.phpdocx.com/

And csv functions in core php itself are legion, plus tons of libraries to help you do all sorts with .csv

Hope that helps